# Constantly getting different predictions for a small data set when using KNN (k = 2) in R

Tags: r, algorithm, knn

Consider this regression problem with the following training set:

[image]

I want to predict the 2-nearest neighbour prediction for each object - however, I keep getting different predictions every time I call the knn function. Should this be the case? Here is the code I'm using:

```
library(class)
test <- train <- matrix(c(-1, 0, 2, 3),,1)
cl <- c(0, 1, 2, 1)
knn(train, test, cl, k=2)
```

Output:

```
> knn(train, test, cl, k=2)
[1] 1 1 2 2
Levels: 0 1 2
> knn(train, test, cl, k=2)
[1] 0 0 1 2
Levels: 0 1 2
> knn(train, test, cl, k=2)
[1] 1 1 1 2
Levels: 0 1 2
> knn(train, test, cl, k=2)
[1] 0 0 1 2
Levels: 0 1 2
```

Would really appreciate any clarification.

Answer (score 6):

In`knn` ties are broken at random and the way you have it setup you will always have exactly one correct (exact match) and one incorrect label (the nearest match) in the vote and thus the result is always a random pick between the actual label and the wrong one.

You can see that empirically by running the experiment many times and looking at the results - each row will have exactly two different outcomes in roughly the same proportion.

Comment: Ah OK, that makes sense. I am working through an exercise in my book which tells me to plot the 2-nearest neighbour prediction for each object against the object (in R). It doesn't provide solutions, but would I be correct in assuming that there will be multiple correct plots for this particular scenario?

Comment: Well, all plots are correct ;). But, yes, on such a small training set the prediction will vary for each call since for `k=2` there will be ties so you will get different plots.

Comment: Cool. Out of curiosity, if I were to do this on paper instead of R will my results still vary massively? Will I still be randomly picking labels? Machine learning isn't something I study so I'm not entirely familiar with the algorithm (yet) but I do plan on looking into it a bit deeper tomorrow.

Comment: It depends how you decide to break ties. The alg simply takes the closest rows (by euclid dist), looks at their labels and picks the most frequent one. For `k=2` you have always two labels so either they are the same (and thus a clear winner) or not. If they are not, then you have to make some decision - let's say If you decide to always take the smaller number then you will get consistent results - but then you will also be more likely to predict smaller numbers. R simply picks one at random so you don't have a specific bias in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the code not working, my guess is that there is a tie and in that case it randomly chooses, which is why you're seeing seeing different results each time you use it.  Choosing k=3 in this case would stop all ties and give you the same answer every time.

Comment: Sorry, check the edit it works now. I set k = 3 and still get different results, I'm not sure what's wrong

Comment: `k=3` won't help: you will always get `1` for the last two rows because the only label that occurs twice (and thus can win outright) is `1` and only the last two rows are close enough to pick both. First two rows will always have 3 different labels and thus always a random pick among them.